# EF doesn't give back a class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

if I do:

```
var organisationList = _context.OrganisationCategory.ToList();
```

It only returns a list without the Organisation and Category. It doesn't give back the organisation and category models but in stead I get a list with:

```
1, null, null
2, null, null
3, null, null
```

I think I made a mistake? In the database are the ID's of the organisation and the category properly set.

OrganisationCategory model:

```
public class OrganisationCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public OrganisationCategory() { }

    public OrganisationCategory(Organisation Organisation, Category Category)
    {
        this.Organisation = Organisation;
        this.Category = Category;
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContextMOdelSnapshot.cs:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity("Implicietmeten.Models.Organisations.Categories.OrganisationCategory", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("ID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<int?>("CategoryID");

                b.Property<int?>("OrganisationID");

                b.HasKey("ID");
            });
```

Comment: Check table foreign key. Looks like no foreign key in tables.

Comment: I was under the impression that EF created the foreign keys by it self? But thank you for the reaction and I will come back to it if it works :-)

Comment: No. First add foreign key to table.

Comment: EF will create foreign keys in a code-first solution. You do not need to manually create them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework Core still not yet supports lazy loading, so you can only use eager loading like this:

```
var organisationList = _context.OrganisationCategory.Include(x => x.Organization).Include(x => x.Category).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the virtual keyword when trying to access the related entities. This will allow entity framework to use lazy loading to load the entities the first time they are accessed.

```
public class OrganisationCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public OrganisationCategory() { }

    public OrganisationCategory(Organisation Organisation, Category Category)
    {
        this.Organisation = Organisation;
        this.Category = Category;
    }
}
```

Comment: only if you do not leave the dbcontexts scope. After that accessing the properties will throw exceptions.

Comment: yes that's true. however, i believe all work with the entities should be done within the scope of the dbcontext. Otherwise I'd use a dto to access the class objects outside of the scope thus forcing the entities to be lazy loaded. I guess it depends on the structure of your code.